# What does it imply when substrate terminal of Nmosfet is short-circuited with the source terminal?

Tags: mosfet

What does it imply when substrate terminal of N-MOSFET is short-circuited with the source terminal?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be homework without demonstrating effort to solve.

Comment: Without more context it's a silly question...such a connection implies virtually nothing, in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this has the appearance of a "homework" question, I'm not going to provide a direct answer. Instead, I offer the following hints:

What can you say about the silicon structure between the substrate and the source/drain terminals? What happens when you short one of them out?